# Binding a Path in the class to an int property

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I would like to bind a property in the source data to an int.  Take for instance:

`<ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding Makes}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Make_ID}" DisplayMemberPath="MakeDesc" />`

From the ViewModel:
`public short Make_ID { get { return Vehicle.Make_ID; } set { Vehicle.Make_ID = value; OnPropertyChanged("Make_ID"); } }`

`Makes` is a class that has ID, MakeDesc, etc.  My View Model is interested in the selected make but only it's ID.  I know I could do this with IValueConverters but I'd rather not have to do that -- I think there is a way to do that on the binding, I just can't remember how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use SelectedValue and SelectedPath instead.

`<ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding Makes}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Make_ID}" SelectedValuePath="ID" DisplayMemberPath="MakeDesc" />`